# Photoshop actions: saving with custom addition

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, automation, actions

I have searched far and wide for this, and cannot figure it out. I create and run an action, but I want the action to save the image with the original name + two custom letters.
Original image is called IMG_3232.jpg
I want the after-action (resize) image called IMG_3232aW.jpg

So of course the whole idea of creating an action is to run this on lots of images, and they all should get the "IMG_xxxxaW.jpg marker.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Displaying my ignorance: it seems to me it will not accept aW as addition to unique file name. It seems to insist I add a running, unique addition - which is what I do not want.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Photoshop go to File → Automate → Batch and you can select the action to use and the file naming of the output files

[image: Batch window]